# How to get a type other than GameObject using GameObject.Find?

Tags: unity, c#

I am Using Unity 2021.3.13f1.

I need to find an object in my scene and  its type is TMP_Text.

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
TMP_Text text = (TMP_Text)(GameObject.Find("TooltipTemplate"));
```

However I get the error:

```
Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'TMPro.TMP_Text'
```

When I remove the explicit cast and add it in Instantiate() below:

```
GameObject text = (GameObject.Find("text"));    
Instantiate((TMP_Text)text, ..., ...);
```

I get the same error.
I conclude that the way I use GameObject.Find, it returns a GameObject type and Unity refuses to cast it to the type I need to use.

**How do I obtain the right type with a search? Be it GameObject or a better method.**

Comment: By the way: when you have a gameObject that is supposed to serve as a "template", then perhaps that should perhaps be a [prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will include prefabs later. However, I am at early stages in the development of my project and going with templates is faster for me right now, I am testing various things constantly.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some misconception here about how Unity works. Specifically about what's the difference between a *GameObject* and a *Component*. GameObjects in Unity are containers for multiple Components. A GameObject that shows up as a text **isn't** a `TMP_Text`. It's a GameObject that **has a** TMP_Text *component*. This confusion might be from how the Unity editor pretends to let you create a `TMP_Text` from the context menu, but what you *actually* get when you do that is a whole GameObject that has multiple components, and among them a `TMP_Text` component.

When you want to get a reference to a specific component of a GameObject, then you call the [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) method of the GameObject where you expect the component to be.

```
GameObject tooltipTemplate = GameObject.Find("TooltipTemplate");
TMP_Text tooltipTemplateText = tooltipTemplate.GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
```

Other options for you might be the static methods [FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) (that gives you the first   component of the first object with such a component) and [FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsByType.html) (that gives you an array with all the components of the given type in the scene). But neither method allows you to specify a name of a specific game object. They are going to search your whole scene for components of that type.

But keep in mind that all the `Find*` methods are generally very slow, because they search through the whole scene tree. If possible, you might want to use other ways to set up references between game objects. For example, by creating a `public TMP_Text text` field in your script and then assign the desired text object in the inspector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what I need to check again to use Unity better. However, I believe, in my case the misconception comes from me being able to do the following: 

```
public TMP_Text TooltipTemplate;
[...]
Instantiate(TooltipTemplate);

```
which returns to me an object I of which I can manipulate the transform and text inside. I assumed it was a GameObject...

I didn't need to manually create a GameObject and assign to it a Text component. Why is such a shortcut possible?

Comment: Also, I had to try to access to this object through Find as it wasn't possible to reference it through a variable inside app.cs: the drag and drop of the object into the variable field of app.cs refused to work. I tried to use a prefab but encountered other issues that made me revert back into .Find method...

Comment: @Mike1979 That behavior of Instantiate is in [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html):  *"If you are cloning a Component the GameObject it is attached to is also cloned"*. That's kind of a trap, because you are also cloning all the other components on the GameObject. The reason why they did it that way is because it's impossible for a component to exist without a GameObject that owns it. But that of course begs the question why Instantiate even accepts a component, when you could just as well do `Instantiate(component.gameObject)`.

Comment: I'd honestly prefer the Instantiate method to throw me an error when I try to clone a component then, but at this point I'll just be careful next time. Thank you again